# svcutil fails locally, works elsewhere with same remote uri

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

When running svcutil.exe against a WCF service after publishing it from VS to a remote server, I got this:

```
> URI: http://myuri/mysvc.svc?wsdl
> 
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
> 'http://myuri/mysvc.svc?wsdl'.
> 
> There was no endpoint listening at http://myuri/mysvc.svc?wsdl that
> could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
> or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
> 
> Unable to connect to the remote server
> 
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it 127.0.0.1:8888
```

After lots of troubleshooting, I finally tried running svcutil against the same uri on other machines, including machines both inside and outside the my network, and get the expected result:

```
Attempting to download metadata from 'http://myuri/mysvc.svc?wsdl' using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO.
Generating files...
C:\Users\Explorer.cs
C:\Users\output.config
```

I disabled the local Windows Firewall, no effect.  So I think I've eliminated:

- Problems with the service configuration itself (svcutil works on other machines)
- Firewall issues (other machines on my network work)

This appears to be local to my machine: something's interfering with svcutil.

Other info:

- The same error appears in Visual Studio when attempting to add the service
  reference
- The uri for the service/WSDL returns the expected result via browser
- I get the same error with *any* uri, not just my service

Anybody seen this?

Comment: Is a proxy issue maybe? IE>settings>connections>lan settings>are you using a proxy server?

Comment: Thanks @Popo.  Nope, no proxy server, and VPN disabled.  One more twist: I fired up Fiddler to trace traffic, and with Fiddler running, both svcutil and VS "Add Service Reference" work as expected!  Shut down Fiddler and both stop working again.  Continuing to look...